# Is it possible to add more than one effect to a Label in Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I'd like to have a label with a blur effect and a drop shadow effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the older [BitmapEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.bitmapeffect.aspx), then you can make use of the BitmapEffectGroup:

```
<Label Content="Hello">
    <Label.BitmapEffect>
        <BitmapEffectGroup>
            <DropShadowBitmapEffect />
            <BlurBitmapEffect />
        </BitmapEffectGroup>
    </Label.BitmapEffect>
</Label>
```

BitmapEffect, however is being depreciated, and UIElement.Effect is the preferred method to add effects.  To combine multiple behaviors into a Effect of this type, you will have to create a custom effect that does what you desire.  [As shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect.aspx), which will require more then just editing the elements through blend.

Also, take a look here: [WPF Pixel Shader Effect Library](http://www.codeplex.com/wpffx)
They have some exelent examples and pre-built effects as well as good tutorial on how to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could just wrap the label in a grid or border and apply the blur effect to that while applying the dropshadow to the label directly.